# Is it possible to use structured bindings to assign class members?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'd like to use C++ 17 structured bindings to assign a value to a class member variable, like this:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

struct Result {
  double value;
  bool error;
};

Result square_root(double input) { return {std::sqrt(input), input < 0}; }

struct Calculator {
  double result_;
  bool error_;

 public:
  void ComputeSquareRoot(double input) {
    [ result_, error_ ] = square_root(input);
  }

  void DisplayResult() {
    if (error_)
      std::cout << "Cannot take the square root of a negative number.\n";
    else
      std::cout << "The square root is " << result_ << ".\n";
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Calculator calc;
  calc.ComputeSquareRoot(64);
  calc.DisplayResult();
}
```

But this code fails to compile with the following error (using clang 5.0):

```
> clang++ structured_bindings.cpp -std=c++17 -o structured_bindings
structured_bindings.cpp:20:7: error: 'result_' in capture list does not name a variable
    [ result_, error_ ] = square_root(input);
      ^
structured_bindings.cpp:20:16: error: 'error_' in capture list does not name a variable
    [ result_, error_ ] = square_root(input);
               ^
structured_bindings.cpp:20:25: error: expected body of lambda expression
    [ result_, error_ ] = square_root(input);
                        ^
3 errors generated.
```

There seems to be some confusion with lambda capture. Certainly this will work:

```
auto[result, error] = square_root(input);
result_ = result;
error_ = error;
```

But I would like to avoid the need to use new local variables. Is this possible with structured bindings?

Comment: I suppose you could put a `Result` object in your `Calculator` instead of separate variables.

Comment: @Galik Yes, this was a bit of a contrived example to demonstrate the question. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) to assign values to existing objects:

```
std::tie(result_, error_) = square_root(input);
```

That's why it was added to C++11. Of course, you'd need to forego using `Result` in favor of a `std::tuple`. Which IMO is better for such ad-hoc "return multiple things" scenarios.

Structured bindings are exclusively for declaring *new* names.

Another approach, which could be even better, since C++1z is on the table, is to not re-invent the wheel. Return a `std::optional`

```
auto square_root(double input) {
   return input < 0 ? std::nullopt : std::optional{std::sqrt(input)}; 
}
```

This has the clear semantics of "there may be a value, or not".

---

By the way, unconditionally calling `std::sqrt` with a negative input is a bad idea. Especially if you don't configure your floating point environment in any special way prior.

Comment: I'm personally not a fan of `std::tuple` in cases like this, as I prefer named values to `get<0>` or `get<1>`, although `std:tie` doesn't look too bad. I think that `std::optional` is better than both though - I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: @JoshPeterson - I do get your point about `std::tuple`. I would usually mitigate it by adding `enum { value, error }`. So the call would look like `std::get<value>(...)`

Comment: "_Structured bindings are exclusively for declaring *new* objects._" This might be a fast way to explain it, but IMO it's quite inaccurate, and AFAICT it just leads to further confusion later when users hit things they don't expect because they were thinking of structured bindings the wrong way. What SBs introduce is new *names* for members (or `get()` invocations, or etc.) of an **existing** object. In this case, the object is the new, invisible, necessarily lifetime-extended result of `square_root()`, but it could just as well be a structure that already existed before the current statement.

Comment: @underscore_d - Sure. Names would be fudging it less than objects.